# Angular 7 - How to implement sorting in mat-table

Tags: html, typescript, angular-material, angular7, angular-material-table

I am trying to implement sorting in `<mat-table>` using Angular version 7.3.

Below is my source code:

```
<table
  mat-table
  [dataSource]='dataSource'>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
  </ng-container>
</table>
```

Here is the TypeScript file source is:

```js
const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
  {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
  {position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},
  {position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be'}
];

@Component({
  selector: 'table-basic-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-basic-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-basic-example.html',
})
export class TableBasicExample {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;
}
```

I am using Angular version 7 and the sorting feature I am not able to write. Need help with that as I am new to Angular.

Answer (score 1):

1. Import `MatSortModule` to `AppModule`.

```js
import { MatSortModule } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...,
    MatSortModule,
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Or if you have another module such as `MaterialModule`:

```js
import { MatSortModule } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  exports: [
    ...,
    MatSortModule,
  ],
  ...
})
export class MaterialModule {}
```

```js
import { MaterialModule } from /* material.module.ts path */;

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...,
    MaterialModule,
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

2.1. Apply `matSort` directive to table (parent) element.

2.2. Apply `mat-sort-header` directive to each `mat-header-cell` element.

(Reference: [Adding sort to table headers](https://v7.material.angular.io/components/sort/overview#adding-sort-to-table-headers))

```
<table
  mat-table
  [dataSource]='dataSource' matSort>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> No. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header mat-sort-header> Weight </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
  </ng-container>

</table>
```

3. Would suggest passing the data by creating a `MatTableDataSource` instance.

```js
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(ELEMENT_DATA);
```

```js
export class TableSortingExample implements OnInit {
  ...
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(ELEMENT_DATA);

  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }
}
```

[Sample Demo on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oqlg7l?file=app/table-sorting-example.html)

---

### Reference

[Sort Header | Angular Material](https://v7.material.angular.io/components/sort/overview)